# Создание страницы в wordpress-е

Tags: php, wordpress, cms, интерфейс, настройки

Я действую согласно [Создание меню](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JQcxO81ojBM&list=PL3LQJkGQtzc6Nwz67GGrMdqxim1c0H5DC&index=3) с 15:07-15:20

У меня в админке wordpress-а возникает следующая последовательность окон

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После нажатия на кнопку Добавить новую возникает окно

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Каким образом можно сделать так, чтобы после нажатия на кнопку Добавить новую возникало окно как на видео

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

?

Подскажите также где об этом (именно о виде окна) написано в интернете.

Comment: Установите плагин [Classic Editor](https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/classic-editor/). Тому видео которое Вы смотрите около 4-х лет, стандартный WYSIWYG редактор был заменен на блочный редактор Gutenberg с релизом версии 5.0, релиз состоялся в декабре 2018 года.

Comment: @Simon мне необходимо вставить html\php код в редактор.

Comment: PHP код из редактора работать не будет, для этого есть другие инструменты.

Comment: @Simon какие инструменты нужны для php кода?

Comment: Обрисуйте задачу нормально. Это не работает таким образом что там где редактируется страница из админ панели, Вы пишете PHP код. Обычно заполнением занимаются люди далекие от знания PHP. Если Вам нужно использовать код в шаблоне страницы, его нужно создать см. [3 способа создать шаблон страницы](https://wp-kama.ru/id_5177/3-sposoba-sozdat-shablon-stranitsyi.html), если нужно добавить кастомные поля, используется [ACF](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/) или его аналоги.

Comment: @Simon спасибо огромнейшее. В курсе https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL3LQJkGQtzc6Nwz67GGrMdqxim1c0H5DC изложение непоследовательное - о шаблонах постов/страниц сказано только на 7-ом уроке. А я остановился только на 4-ом (про сайдбары).